# PHP Xdebug dosen't show variables

Tags: php, debugging, xampp, xdebug, superglobals

PHP Xdebug always says `POST` (superglobal) undefined but web program works fine. Either of other local variables or Superglobals aren't shown. I use XAMPP as local server. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, you can upgrade your Xdebug version to resolve the issue
2. You need to use a conditional statement `isset()` on the form's input name element, for example,

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name=$_POST["name"];
}
```